# Make a database and tables via php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to create a database automatically, execute /tmp/tmp.sql that describes the template table, and register it in the newly created database.

```
<?php
    //create db
    $uuid= "uniqueID";
    $dbname = $uuid.'_reservedb';

    //connectーーーーーーーーーーーーーーーー
    $dsn = 'mysql:;host=localhost';
    $user = 'root';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user);
        print_r("success\n");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print_r('Error:'.$e->getMessage());
        die();
    }
    print_r($dbname."\n");

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = file_get_contents('/tmp/tmp.sql');
    $rtn=$dbh->exec($sql);
    if($rtn){
        print_r("OK\n");
    }else
        print_r("NG\n");;
    ?>
```

It shows message "success" and "OK", but there is not new database named "success
uniqueID_reservedb" checked from SQL command "show databases;"
I confirmed with the SQL command "show databases", but there is no new database.

Of course, /tmp/tmp.sql is not running.

Please let me know what's wrong?

Comment: I don't see a command that creates a new database. you just create some PHP variable

Answer (score -1):

[exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) returns number or rows affected or FALSE, so your test is incorrect as per the documentation.

Note: it says executes **A** SQL statement, not many.